# Jenkins/Sonar timeout: Socket closed

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube

We have many projects which are basically branches from a master branch
Most of them run successfully but few fail randomly with below error.
I would appreciate it very much if I can get help on this issue

**Jenkins ver**. 2.32.2;   **Sonarqube ver** 6.2;   **mysql** 5.7

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 45:24 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-12T12:06:20+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 1391M/4453M

 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) 
    on project shrek-all: Fail to request http://shrek.sdomain.co.jp/sonarqube/api/ce/submit?projectKey=jp.co.shrek:shrek-
    all&projectName=Shrek%20All&projectBranch=0005-shrek-form_v3: timeout: Socket closed -> [Help 1]


017.06.12 12:06:41 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:06:41 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:07:21 INFO  ce[AVyaQqm7axEU2tgjAh4B][o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Execute task | project=jp.co.shrek:shrek-all:master | type=REPORT | id=AVyaQqm7axEU2tgjAh4B
2017.06.12 12:07:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:07:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:08:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:08:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:09:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:09:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:10:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:10:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:11:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:11:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:12:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:12:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:13:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:13:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:14:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:14:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:15:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:15:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:16:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:16:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:17:34 INFO  ce[AVyaQqm7axEU2tgjAh4B][o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | jp.co.shrek:shrek-all:master | type=REPORT | id=AVyaQqm7axEU2tgjAh4B | time=613407ms
2017.06.12 12:17:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:17:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:18:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
2017.06.12 12:18:43 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
```

I would like to point out that our projects is super big. 2,087,509
lines of code. Please see this part also in the logs "**time=613407ms**"

Comment: You should update your question with debug logs (_sonar.verbose=true_) of the analysis (with timestamps too), that should give more visibility into exchanges between the scanner and server.

Comment: Much more detail is required here. I investigated a similar issue that turned out to be a backup job running on the SonarQube host. It was consuming all resources on the server so it was refusing connections. Had nothing to do with either Jenkins or SonarQube specifically. Are the failures really "random" or do they happen mostly at certain points of the day? For all jobs or just certain ones? Etc.

Comment: @NicolasB.-SonarSourceTeam I added CE logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to limitation of our linux server. when more than 3 jobs are executing at the same time, this issue occurs randomly. After setting the no. of executors to 2, it was OK.

Answer (score 2):

If you *know* the server running SonarQube is slow and you can live with that (like I do for my cheap but brave little server hosting, building, analysing and running my private test projects) and you are sure there are no other issues (or don't care about them), you can add the parameter `sonar.ws.timeout` and set it to the maximum number of seconds you like to wait for a request to SonarQube to complete.

See [*Analysis Parameters* in the SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) for a list of available parameters.

Comment: I upated timeout to 1000 seconds still its throwing same error.

Comment: ERROR: Fail to request http://localhost:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=myui&projectName=myui
ERROR: Caused by: timeout
ERROR: Caused by: Socket closed